# MongoDB > extract collection from nested array

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've been trying every method I found on SO with no success. Trying
to accomplish a seemingly simple task (very easy with json/lodash for example) in MongoDB..

I have a collection:
db.users >

```
[
    {
        _id: 'userid',
        profile: {
            username: 'abc',
            tests: [
                {
                    _id: 'testid',
                    meta: {
                        category: 'math',
                        date: '9/2/2017',
                        ...
                    }
                    questions: [
                        {
                            type: 'add',
                            correct: true,
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'subtract',
                            correct: true,
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'add',
                            correct: false,
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'multiply',
                            correct: false,
                        },

                    ]
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

I want to end up with an array grouped by question type:

```
[
    {
        type: 'add',
        correct: 5,
        wrong: 3,
    },
    {
        type: 'subtract',
        correct: 4,
        wrong: 9
    }
    ...
]
```

I've tried different variations of aggregate, last one is:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { $match: { 'profile.tests.meta.category': 'math' }},
    { 
        $project: {
            tests: {
               $filter: {
                  input: "$profile.tests",
                  as: "test",
                  cond: { $eq: ['$$test.meta.category', 'math'] }
               }
            }
         }
    },
    { 
        $project: {
            question: "$tests.questions"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$questions"},

])
```

Also tried adding $group at the end of the pipeline:

```
{
        $group:
        {
            _id: '$questions.type',
            res: {
                $addToSet: { correct: {$eq:['$questions.chosenAnswer', '$questions.answers.correct'] }
            }
        }
    }
```

No variation gave me what I'm looking for, I'm sure I'm missing a core concept, I've looked over the documentation and couldn't figure it out.. what I'm basically looking for is a flatMap to extract away all the questions of all users and group them by type.

If anyone can lead me in the right direction, I'll greatly appreciate it :) thx. (Also, I'm using Meteor, so any query has to work in Meteor mongo)

Comment: sorry, only copied relevant fields, but it's a mistake, should be meta>category>math instead of just category.. I'll update the Q, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4.

`$filter` to filter `math` categories with `$map` to project `questions` array in each matching category followed by `$reduce` and `$concatArrays` to get all `questions` into single array for all matching categories.

`$unwind` questions array and `$group` by `type` and `$sum` to compute `correct` and `wrong` count.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "profile.tests.meta.category": "math"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "questions": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$map": {
              "input": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$profile.tests",
                  "as": "testf",
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": [
                      "$$testf.meta.category",
                      "math"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              "as": "testm",
              "in": "$$testm.questions"
            }
          },
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$questions"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$questions.type",
      "correct": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$questions.correct",
                true
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "wrong": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$questions.correct",
                false
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: you seriously made my day.. thanks for taking the time.

Comment: I'm new to MongoDB, trying to understand exactly what you did, will dig in deeply on $reduce for sure :), it seems this query actually runs pretty fast when testing, do you have any tips for further optimizations? I know indexes should be created, is that relevant here? I was told to extract all questions to their own collection.. is that something you would suggest doing in this case.. or they're good where they are? thank you.

Comment: Np. You can only use indexes for `$match` stage. So add index for `profile.tests.meta.category`. You have to test all the options before picking one. I would also try moving the questions to the top level and into its own array with relevant meta data to tie it back to associated test  ( in essence duplicating some of the data). You can also now add `$match` for questions should you need. Compare this option against the current structure and option moving into its own collection.